# emscripten and dynamic linking: how to link with embind?

Tags: emscripten, embind

I am trying to use dynamic linking with emscripten plus the embind library.

Side modules are built with `-s SIDE_MODULE=1` whereas the main module is built with `-s MAIN_MODULE=1`. Everything's fine until I start using embind in one side module. I then have runtime error as described bellow:

If I don't build with `--bind` at all, I get:
`external function '_emval_get_global' is missing`

Now if I build the side module only with `--bind`, I get:
`external function '_embind_register_void'`

If I only build the main module with `--bind`, I get
`BindingError: parameter 0 has unknown type N10emscripten3valE,BindingError`

And if I build both modules with `--bind`, I get
`BindingError: Cannot register type 'void' twice`

Important :

- I have EMCC_FORCE_STDLIBS=1 in my env.
- The code used is taken directly from https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#using-val-to-transliterate-javascript-to-c
- If I put this same code in the *main_module*, then everythings fine (with the --bind option used)

Any idea ?

Comment: This is likely https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/pull/18418